# Is there a resource where I can donwload E. coli assemblies grouped by their pathotypes?

Tags: genome, public-databases, assembly, microbiology

I will preface this by saying I'm not a microbiologist, so I apologise for any haziness and I'll be happy to expand.

I would like to download the assemblies of different E. coli genomes and group them by their pathotypes (e.g. EPEC, ETEC, EIEC).

I have used enterobase previously to download salmonella genomes broadly by their subspecies, and it does have a set of E. coli genomes. However, they are mainly annotated by their serotype, and not with any broad nomination of pathogenesis. I think I would be able to use the API to grab these serotypes and map them to a type of pathogenicity but that would probably be quite messy.

Does such a database exist? Most I can find are broadly annotated or a are very detailed, but don't allow access to the raw annotation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ENA archive contains such information, then you can access it programatically through the [EBI api](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/browse/programmatic-access).

Also you can access the NCBI database programatically through their [eutils](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25500/).

In both cases you can access annotations, though not sure if they contain what you are looking for in all the cases.

Comment: Thanks for that! I previously tried the NCBI and it turned out to be quite messy. The ENA is a step in the right direction as I can extract the strain information quite nicely. Not quite what I was after but definitely helpful, thanks.